# Initializing AssetManager in Groovy Console

Tags: groovy, aem

My goal is to programmatically move assets. I have found that AssetManager has a moveAsset method. However, I am having issues initializing an AssetManager object in my groovy script. Below is the code I am working with.  How do I initialize a non-null AssetManager object?

```
import javax.jcr.query.*
import com.day.cq.dam.api.*

def query = createSQL2Query("/content/dam/3d-renders/application-notes/wcc-migration") //CHANGE THIS
def result = query.execute()
def rows = result.rows

rows.each { row ->
    Resource res = resourceResolver.getResource(null,row.path)
    AssetManager am = res.adaptTo(AssetManager.class)
    am.getAsset('/content/dam/3d-renders/application-notes/wcc-migration/Q60_ILL000347_iAPP.psd')
    println res.path + ' ' + am
    //am.moveAsset('/content/dam/3d-renders/application-notes/wcc-migration/2015/Q3X-Color-Mark-Sensing.psd','/content/dam/3d-renders/test-folder/Q3X-Color-Mark-Sensing.psd')

}

def createSQL2Query(startPage) {
    def queryManager = session.workspace.queryManager
    def statement = "select * from [nt:base] as p where (isdescendantnode   (p, '$startPage')) and p.[jcr:primaryType] = 'dam:Asset'"
    def query = queryManager.createQuery(statement, Query.JCR_SQL2)
    query
}
```

Comment: How about `AssetManager am = resourceResolver.adaptTo(AssetManager.class)`? `ResourceResolver` implements  `Adaptable`, which is where the `adaptTo(Class)` method comes is defined. See https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/javadoc/com/adobe/granite/asset/api/AssetManager.html

Comment: That worked, however, if I do `am.assetExists('/content/dam/3d-renders/application-notes/wcc-migration/Q60_ILL000347_iAPP.psd')`, it throws an error saying No signature of method. Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't see a `AssetManager.assetsExists()` method in the API. `getAsset()` returns null if the asset doesn't exist, so you should be able to use that. And Groovy provides a shortcut; ex: `if(am.getAsset('blah')) { /* asset was found */}`. Although, honestly, I don't know what the hell I'm talking about. I simply found the API online and inferred from there.

Comment: are you sure you are using `com.day.cq.dam.api.AssetManager` and not `com.adobe.granite.asset.api.AssetManager`? the methods you mentioned do not exist in cq dam api but do in granite assets api

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa the granite.asset.api has a assetExists() method shown here https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/javadoc/com/adobe/granite/asset/api/AssetManager.html.

Comment: @awadheshv yeah, I noticed that and imported the granite assets api and I still get the same problem.

Comment: Go ahead and add the code you have so far to your question. So we are all on the same page.

Comment: @awadheshv I was originally importing both the cq and granite apis.  After removing the cq one, it is working as intended. Thank you for the help

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa if you want to post your comment as an answer, I can mark this question as correct since you posted the working solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try getting your asset manager like this:

```
AssetManager am = resourceResolver.adaptTo(AssetManager.class)
```

`ResourceResolver` implements `Adaptable`, the interface where the `adaptTo(Class)` method is defined.